# Regex to check if http or https exists in the string

Tags: javascript, regex

So i have this code:

```
function validateText(str)
{
    var tarea = str;
    var tarea_regex = /^(http|https)/;
    if(tarea_regex.test(String(tarea).toLowerCase()) == true)
    {
        $('#textVal').val('');
    }
}
```

This works perfectly for this:

https://hello.com

http://hello.com

but not for:

this is a website http://hello.com asdasd asdasdas

tried doing some reading but i dont where to place * ? since they will check the expression anywhere on the string according here -> http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

thank you

Comment: fwiw, http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ is a great way to learn about regex.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the looks of it, you're just checking if http or https exists in the string. Regular expressions are a bit overkill for that purpose. Try this simple code using `indexOf`:

```
function validateText(str)
{
    var tarea = str;
    if (tarea.indexOf("http://") == 0 || tarea.indexOf("https://") == 0) {
        // do something here
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, let me try this. tried it but it sees every value of tarea as http or https

Comment: it empties the value for any input

Comment: Yes, that was a logic error on my part as pointed out by @Dan Tao. Fixed now.

Answer (score 27):

Try this:

```
function validateText(string) {
  if(/(http(s?)):\/\//i.test(string)) {
    // do something here
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry. my bad :)

Answer (score 5):

The `^` in the beginning matches the start of the string. Just remove it.

```
var tarea_regex = /^(http|https)/;
```

should be

```
var tarea_regex = /(http|https)/;
```

Answer (score 4):

```
((http(s?))\://))
```

Plenty of ideas here : http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

Comment: Thanks, works fine for me when removing extra ) and adding slashes
/((http(s?))\://)/

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried using a word break instead of the start-of-line character?

```
var tarea_regex = /\b(http|https)/;
```

It seems to do what I *think* you want. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/BejGd/

Comment: sorry I haven't. i'm partially new to regex and i was not certain what they meant with wordbreak.